# Values for $p$ where series converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\ln n}{\mathrm{n}^{3p}}$$
Which interval of p does this series converge to? I understand that p can go up to infinity but I don't know how to get the left endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $p>1/3$. If $p\le 1/3$ it is divergent because it is bigger than the harmonic series. For $p>1/3$ however, you call $q=3p>1$ and you can compare

$$
\frac{\log n}{n^q}\le\frac{\log n}{n^{1+(q-1)/2}n^{(q-1)/2}}\le \frac{C}{n^{1+(q-1)/2}} 
$$
which is convergent (I used the fact that $\frac{\log n}{n^{\alpha}}\to 0$ for any $\alpha>0$).